# Would this kernel source work?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cyanogenmod

i have an Archos 50 Helium Plus phone, this phone uses a MT6735P MTK chipset, Archos didn't release the source code of the phone kernel, however, i found a Lenovo phone, the Lenovo Vibe C2, that uses the exact same MTK chipset MT6735P as my archos phone and the source of the kernel of this phone is publicly available containing the vendor and device trees and the kernel source

I wonder if using this source could work for my phone, since the two phones have the exact same hardware chipset

i'd like, with it to build TWRP recovery and Cyanogenmod for this phone

Comment: *"Would this kernel source work?"* -- It would have most (and maybe all) the salient drivers.  But besides the source code you would need a  kernel **.config** file to build a suitable kernel, as well as the proper Device Tree.  The MT6735P is a SoC, not a *"chipset"*.  SoCs tend to have more integrated peripherals than what can be connected to a PCB (and actually used)  at one time.  So a SoC installed on one board could be configured quite differently from the same SoC on another board.  IOW the source is merely a starting point; you need a lot more information to build a working kernel.

Comment: I see, i've actually downloaded the lenovo source, it contains folders such as Device,Vendor,bootable,external,hardware,kernel-3.18,frameworks and trusty

Comment: from what i've seen in the source in the kernel folder there is a .config file

Comment: A **.config** file could be bloated to encompass several SoCs, or pared down to the essentials for just one SoC on one board.  You'll have to figure out what you have.  BTW source code tarballs do not have *"folders"*.  Folder is a GUI concept.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to ask Archos directly for the source code for your phone model (https://www.archos.com/fr/support/support_tech/contact_support.html).

They have to give you the source code of their own version of Android according to GPL 2.0 (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Comment: I've tried to contact them multiple times but it looks like the contact mails and phone number they give are people who don't know about this kind of thing and are only here for repairing broken devices and things like this, i tried to contact them they always send me an other mail or phone number and at the end, no real answer